# Footnote packages striking

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

Please, note that this is not a duplicate problem...

I would like to make my footnotes to be come stuck to the very bottom of the page (for this, I tried packages like `footmisc` and it works well).

I also need the footnotes to be always split into two columns (and, for this, I only found the `dblfnote` package, which does this exclusive job).

The problem is that these packages can't work along with each other. How to solve it?

Comment: Please add a [minimal (non-working) example](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can combine `dblfnote` with `fnpos`.  See the [documentation the `yafoot` bundle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/yafoot) to which these belong.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewSwann. I got the results after your suggestion. Please, rewrite your comment in the answer so that I can select it as the correct one to my question. Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dblfnote` belongs to the [`yafoot` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/yafoot).  This bundle also includes `fnpos` which provides a mechanism to put the footnotes at the very bottom of pages, even when `raggedbottom` is in use.  The two packages cooperate together, as the following example shows.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dblfnote,fnpos}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\raggedbottom
\makeFNbottom
\DFNalwaysdouble

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\begin{displaymath}
  y=x
\end{displaymath}
\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]\footnote{\lipsum[5]}
\begin{displaymath}
  y=x
\end{displaymath}
\lipsum[6]

\lipsum[7]\footnote{\lipsum[8]}
\begin{displaymath}
  y=x
\end{displaymath}
\lipsum[9]

\lipsum[10]\footnote{\lipsum[11]}
\begin{displaymath}
  y=x
\end{displaymath}
\lipsum[12]

\end{document}
```